# How to "read" SSD LED display by sniffing it's i2c communications with master?

Tags: i2c, linux

Firstly I apologise if this question is more of a Raspberry Pi/Linux question but I've scoured the Raspi/Linux stack exchange boards and googled until my fingers fell off so I'm trying here in the hope of some assistance!

I have a custom built device which displays certain numerical values on an custom seven segment LED board (6, 6 and 3 segments if it matters). The device is controlled by its master board using the I2C protocol. It is my aim to be able to "listen in" on any commands being sent to the LED board and use the numbers elsewhere. My goal is to have a headless Raspberry Pi acting as an internal web server which will be able to display the values on the LED board saving our engineers a walk every time they need access to the readouts.

The device manufacturer is a bit reticent with information but I am informed that the I2C address of the LED board is 0x88 which is in the reserved range of I2C addresses and therefore I cannot get programs like i2cdetect to successfully query the board.

So my question I guess is: is it possible to listen in to all communications over I2C and extract the useful data? I only want to "read" and not to "write". If I can somehow get the stream of data then I'm sure I'll be able to decode it. Or would it be possible to somehow set up the Pi to also pretend it's a device at address 0x88?

Comment: I'd buy the camera module for the pi! ;-)

Comment: You need a "[Bus Pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate)", which is designed specifically for this task.

Comment: Ha the camera might not be such a bad idea. Not so elegant though.

Thanks Dave for the bus pirate idea, I'll read up on it and see if it might help.

it's a pity really, I was quietly hoping for a one line answer like

do i2c_get_stream(0x88)

Comment: The RPI's Broadcom SoC has i2c slave support available, but the linux drivers for it does not. Also the pin 19 for it is not broken out (as far as I could find out). You could use a simple microcontroller with a modified i2c implementation (read only, no responses, dump data to a serial port/uart once the i2c stop signal is seen). Other than that, if you give us the part number of the led controller, we could help you better.